# Problema al usar imagen en juego Pong con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estoy tratando de adaptar un código que encontré googleando para el juego Pong. Lo que intento es remplazar la pelota dibujada  por una imagen de una pelota en imagen. Buscando en Internet sugieren que use el siguiente código:

```
 var img = new Image(200,200);
 img.src = "img.jpg";
 contexto.clearRect(0,0,700,500);
 contexto.drawImage(img, x, y);
```

El cual inserto casi al final del código en la sección "ball" pero esto no me resulta, y manda error. Todo falla cuando hago la modificación en pong js. al agregar esta linea `ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);`.

Éste es el archivo js llamado pong.js

```
//=============================================================================
// PONG
//=============================================================================

Pong = {

  Defaults: {
    width:     640,   // logical canvas width (browser will scale to physical canvas size - which is controlled by @media css queries)
    height:    480,   // logical canvas height (ditto)
    wallWidth: 10,
    balls:     1,
    stats:     true
  },

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  initialize: function(runner, cfg) {
    this.cfg    = cfg;
    this.runner = runner;
    this.width  = runner.width;
    this.height = runner.height;
    this.court  = Object.construct(Pong.Court,  this);
    this.balls  = this.constructBalls();
    this.runner.start();
  },

  constructBalls: function() {
    var balls = [];
    for(var n = 0 ; n < this.cfg.balls ; n++)
      balls.push(Object.construct(Pong.Ball, this));
    return balls;
  },

  update: function(dt) {
    for(var n = 0 ; n < this.balls.length ; n++)
      this.balls[n].update(dt);
  },

  draw: function(ctx) {
    this.court.draw(ctx);
    for(var n = 0 ; n < this.balls.length; n++)
      this.balls[n].draw(ctx);
  },

  //==========
  // COURT
  //=============================================================================

  Court: {

    initialize: function(pong) {
      var w  = pong.width;
      var h  = pong.height;
      var ww = pong.cfg.wallWidth;

      this.walls = [];
      this.walls.push({x: 0,    y: 0,      width: w,  height: ww});
      this.walls.push({x: 0,    y: h - ww, width: w,  height: ww});
      this.walls.push({x: 0,    y: 0,      width: ww, height:  h});
      this.walls.push({x: w-ww, y: 0,      width: ww, height:  h});
    },

    draw: function(ctx) {
      ctx.fillStyle = '#96ef10';
      for(var n = 0 ; n < this.walls.length ; n++)
        ctx.fillRect(this.walls[n].x, this.walls[n].y, this.walls[n].width, this.walls[n].height);
    }

  },


  // BALL
  //=============================================================================

  Ball: {

    initialize: function(pong) {
      this.pong    = pong;
      this.radius  = Game.random(1, 30);
      this.minX    = pong.cfg.wallWidth + this.radius;
      this.minY    = pong.cfg.wallWidth + this.radius;
      this.maxX    = pong.width  - pong.cfg.wallWidth - this.radius;
      this.maxY    = pong.height - pong.cfg.wallWidth - this.radius;
      this.x       = Game.random(this.minX, this.maxX);
      this.y       = Game.random(this.minY, this.maxY);
      this.dx      = (this.maxX - this.minX) / (Game.random(1, 10) * Game.randomChoice(1, -1));
      this.dy      = (this.maxY - this.minY) / (Game.random(1, 10) * Game.randomChoice(1, -1));

    },

    update: function(dt, leftPaddle, rightPaddle) {

      this.x = this.x + (this.dx * dt);
      this.y = this.y + (this.dy * dt);

      if ((this.dx > 0) && (this.x > this.maxX)) {
        this.x = this.maxX;
        this.dx = -this.dx;
      }
      else if ((this.dx < 0) && (this.x < this.minX)) {
        this.x = this.minX;
        this.dx = -this.dx;
      }

      if ((this.dy > 0) && (this.y > this.maxY)) {
        this.y = this.maxY;
        this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
      else if ((this.dy < 0) && (this.y < this.minY)) {
        this.y = this.minY;
        this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
    },

    draw: function(ctx) {
      var w = h = this.radius * 2;
      var img = new Image(200,200);
      img.src = "pelota.png";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      ctx.fill();
      //   Si pongo esta linea ocurre el error ///  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
      ctx.closePath();     
    }
  }

}; // Pong
```

Aquí dejo el código completo. Incluye el archivo pong.js de arriba y un segundo archivo JS llamado game.js que es un poco largo, pero este funciona correctamente:

```js
/**** GAME.JS *****/
/*
   Pong implemented with HTML features.

    Version: 1.1
    Author: David Laurell <david@laurell.nu>
   License: GPLv3

      This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
      it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
      the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
      (at your option) any later version.

      This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
      but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
      MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
       GNU General Public License for more details.

       You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
       along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
      */

var game, canvas, ctx, soundLeft, soundRight, soundWall, gameTimeLast;

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  soundLeft = document.getElementById("bounceLeft");
  soundRight = document.getElementById("bounceRight");
  soundWall = document.getElementById("bounceWall");

  game = {
    player : {
      y : canvas.height / 2,
      score : 0
    },
    computer : {
      y : canvas.height / 2,
      score : 0,
      speed: 2
    },
    ball : {
      x : canvas.width / 2,
      y : canvas.height / 2,
      vx : Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1,
      vy : Math.random() * 4 - 2,
      bounces : 0,
      radius : 3,
      reset: function() {
        this.x = canvas.width / 2;
        this.y = canvas.height / 2;
        this.vy = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
      },
      multiplier: .2,
      maxspeed: 5
    },
    playerHeight : 80,
    playerWidth : 4,
    pause : false,
    sound: true
  };

  document.onmousemove = moveMouse;

  gameTimeLast = new Date();
  update();
}

function moveMouse(e) {
  var y; 
  if(!e) {
    e = window.event;
    y = e.event.offsetY;
  }
  else {
    y = e.pageY;
  }

  y -= canvas.offsetTop;
  if(y - game.playerHeight/2 >= 0 && y + game.playerHeight/2 <= canvas.height)
    game.player.y = y;
}

function playSound(snd) {
  if(game.sound) {
    try {
      if (!snd.paused) {
        // Pause and reset it
        snd.pause(); 
        snd.currentTime = 0;
      }
      snd.play();
    }
    catch(e) {}
  }
}

function update() {
  dateTime = new Date();

  gameTime = (dateTime - gameTimeLast);
  if(gameTime < 0)
    gameTime = 0;

  moveAmount = gameTime > 0 ? gameTime / 10 : 1;

  if (!game.pause) {
    /* Move cpu player */
    if(game.computer.y + 20 < game.ball.y && game.computer.y +   game.playerHeight/2 <= canvas.height)
      game.computer.y += game.computer.speed * moveAmount;
    else if(game.computer.y - 20 > game.ball.y && game.computer.y - game.playerHeight/2 >= 0)
      game.computer.y -= game.computer.speed * moveAmount;

    /* Change direction of ball when hitting a wall */
    if (game.ball.y + game.ball.radius > canvas.height
        || game.ball.y - game.ball.radius < 0) {
      playSound(soundWall);
      if(game.ball.y <= game.ball.radius)
        game.ball.y = game.ball.radius;
      else
        game.ball.y = canvas.height - game.ball.radius;

      game.ball.vy *= -1;
    }

    /* checking collision between ball and player */
    if (game.ball.x + game.ball.radius >= canvas.width - game.playerWidth) {
      if (game.ball.y + game.ball.radius >= game.player.y - game.playerHeight / 2
          && game.ball.y + game.ball.radius <= game.player.y + game.playerHeight / 2) {
        playSound(soundRight);

        if(game.ball.vx <= game.ball.maxspeed) {
          game.ball.vx += game.ball.multiplier;
        }

        changeBallDirection(game.player);
      } else {
        game.computer.score++;
        document.getElementById("computerScore").innerHTML =  game.computer.score;
        game.ball.reset();
        game.ball.vx = -1;
      }
    }
    /* checking collision between ball and cpu */
    else if(game.ball.x - game.ball.radius <= game.playerWidth) {  
      if (game.ball.y + game.ball.radius >= game.computer.y -    game.playerHeight / 2
          && game.ball.y + game.ball.radius <= game.computer.y + game.playerHeight / 2) {
        playSound(soundLeft);

        if(game.ball.vx >= -game.ball.maxspeed) {
          game.ball.vx -= game.ball.multiplier;
        }

        changeBallDirection(game.computer);
      } else {
        game.player.score++;
        document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML =  game.player.score;
        game.ball.reset();
        game.ball.vx = 1;
      }
    }
    game.ball.x += game.ball.vx * moveAmount;
    game.ball.y += game.ball.vy * moveAmount;
  }

  draw();

  setTimeout(update,1000/30);

  gameTimeLast = dateTime;
}

function changeBallDirection(player) {
  if(player.y > game.ball.y)
    game.ball.vy -= (player.y - game.ball.y) / game.playerHeight *    game.ball.maxspeed;
  else if(player.y < game.ball.y)
    game.ball.vy += (game.ball.y - player.y) / game.playerHeight *   game.ball.maxspeed;

  game.ball.vx *= -1;
}
/**
    * Draw everything in the canvas
     */
function draw() {
  if (!game.pause) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    /*
  var bgFade = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,canvas.height);
  bgFade.addColorStop(0, '#000');
  bgFade.addColorStop(1, '#211');
  ctx.fillStyle = bgFade;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     */

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(64,64,64)";
    var size = 3;
    for(var y=0;y<canvas.height;y+=size*3) {
      ctx.fillRect(canvas.width / 2 - size/2, y, size, size);
    }

    // left player
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128,128,128,.8)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, game.computer.y - game.playerHeight / 2,
                 game.playerWidth, game.playerHeight);
    // right player
    ctx.fillRect(canvas.width - game.playerWidth, game.player.y
                 - game.playerHeight / 2, game.playerWidth, game.playerHeight);

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(192,192,192,8)";
    ctx.fillRect(game.ball.x - game.ball.radius, game.ball.y
                 - game.ball.radius, game.ball.radius * 2, game.ball.radius * 2);
  }
}

function intro() {
  var playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
  playButton.onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('titleScreen').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('playScreen').style.display = "block";
    init();
  }

  var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pauseButton');
  pauseButton.onclick = function() {
    if (!game.pause) {
      game.pause = true;
      this.innerHTML = "Continue";
      document.getElementById('pauseText').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      game.pause = false;
      this.innerHTML = "Pause";
      document.getElementById('pauseText').style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var soundButton = document.getElementById('soundButton');
  soundButton.onclick = function() {
    if (!game.sound) {
      game.sound = true;
      this.innerHTML = "Turn off sound";
    }
    else {
      game.sound = false;
      this.innerHTML = "Turn on sound";
    }
  }
}

intro();




/**** PONG.JS *****/

//=============================================================================
// PONG
//=============================================================================

Pong = {

  Defaults: {
    width:     640,   // logical canvas width (browser will scale to physical canvas size - which is controlled by @media css queries)
    height:    480,   // logical canvas height (ditto)
    wallWidth: 10,
    balls:     1,
    stats:     true
  },

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  initialize: function(runner, cfg) {
    this.cfg    = cfg;
    this.runner = runner;
    this.width  = runner.width;
    this.height = runner.height;
    this.court  = Object.construct(Pong.Court,  this);
    this.balls  = this.constructBalls();
    this.runner.start();
  },

  constructBalls: function() {
    var balls = [];
    for(var n = 0 ; n < this.cfg.balls ; n++)
      balls.push(Object.construct(Pong.Ball, this));
    return balls;
  },

  update: function(dt) {
    for(var n = 0 ; n < this.balls.length ; n++)
      this.balls[n].update(dt);
  },

  draw: function(ctx) {
    this.court.draw(ctx);
    for(var n = 0 ; n < this.balls.length; n++)
      this.balls[n].draw(ctx);
  },

  //==========
  // COURT
  //=============================================================================

  Court: {

    initialize: function(pong) {
      var w  = pong.width;
      var h  = pong.height;
      var ww = pong.cfg.wallWidth;

      this.walls = [];
      this.walls.push({x: 0,    y: 0,      width: w,  height: ww});
      this.walls.push({x: 0,    y: h - ww, width: w,  height: ww});
      this.walls.push({x: 0,    y: 0,      width: ww, height:  h});
      this.walls.push({x: w-ww, y: 0,      width: ww, height:  h});
    },

    draw: function(ctx) {
      ctx.fillStyle = '#96ef10';
      for(var n = 0 ; n < this.walls.length ; n++)
        ctx.fillRect(this.walls[n].x, this.walls[n].y, this.walls[n].width, this.walls[n].height);
    }

  },


  // BALL
  //=============================================================================

  Ball: {

    initialize: function(pong) {
      this.pong    = pong;
      this.radius  = Game.random(1, 30);
      this.minX    = pong.cfg.wallWidth + this.radius;
      this.minY    = pong.cfg.wallWidth + this.radius;
      this.maxX    = pong.width  - pong.cfg.wallWidth - this.radius;
      this.maxY    = pong.height - pong.cfg.wallWidth - this.radius;
      this.x       = Game.random(this.minX, this.maxX);
      this.y       = Game.random(this.minY, this.maxY);
      this.dx      = (this.maxX - this.minX) / (Game.random(1, 10) * Game.randomChoice(1, -1));
      this.dy      = (this.maxY - this.minY) / (Game.random(1, 10) * Game.randomChoice(1, -1));

    },

    update: function(dt, leftPaddle, rightPaddle) {

      this.x = this.x + (this.dx * dt);
      this.y = this.y + (this.dy * dt);

      if ((this.dx > 0) && (this.x > this.maxX)) {
        this.x = this.maxX;
        this.dx = -this.dx;
      }
      else if ((this.dx < 0) && (this.x < this.minX)) {
        this.x = this.minX;
        this.dx = -this.dx;
      }

      if ((this.dy > 0) && (this.y > this.maxY)) {
        this.y = this.maxY;
        this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
      else if ((this.dy < 0) && (this.y < this.minY)) {
        this.y = this.minY;
        this.dy = -this.dy;
      }
    },

    draw: function(ctx) {
      var w = h = this.radius * 2;
      var img = new Image(200,200);
      img.src = "pelota.png";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,700,500);
      //   Si pongo esta linea ocurre el error ///  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
      ctx.closePath();     
    }
  }

}; // Pong





/**** CODIGO PARA INICIAR EL JUEGO ****/
Game.ready(function() {
  Game.start('game', Pong);
});
```

```css
body { background-image: url("cancha.jpg"); color: #AAA; font-size: 12pt;     padding: 1em; }

#unsupported { border: 1px solid yellow; color: black; background-color:   #FFFFAD; padding: 2em; margin: 1em; display: inline-block; }

#sidebar                        { width: 18em; height: 40em; float: left;       font-size: 0.825em; background-color: #333; border: 1px solid white; padding:   1em;  }
#sidebar h2                     { color: white; text-align: center;   margin: 0; }
#sidebar .parts                 { padding-left: 1em; list-style-type:   none; margin-bottom: 2em; text-align: right; }
#sidebar .parts li a            { color: white; text-decoration: none; }
#sidebar .parts li a:visited    { color: white; }
#sidebar .parts li a:hover      { color: white; text-decoration: underline; }
#sidebar .parts li a.selected   { color: #F08010; }
#sidebar .parts li a i          { color: #AAA;    }
#sidebar .parts li a.selected i { color: #F08010; }
#sidebar .settings              { line-height: 1.2em; height: 1.2em; text-  align: right; }
#sidebar .settings.size         { }
#sidebar .settings.speed        { margin-bottom: 1em; }
#sidebar .settings label        { vertical-align: middle; }
#sidebar .settings input        { vertical-align: middle; }
#sidebar .settings select       { vertical-align: middle; }
#sidebar .description           { margin-bottom: 2em; }
#sidebar .description b         { font-weight: normal; color: #FFF; }


@media screen and (min-width: 0px) {
  #sidebar { display: none; }
  #game    { display: block; width: 480px; height: 360px; margin: 0 auto; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  #game    { width: 640px; height: 480px; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #sidebar { display: block; }
  #game    { margin-left: 18em; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #game    { width: 800px; height: 600px; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
  #game    { width: 1024px; height: 768px; }
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<div id="sidebar">
  <div class='description'>
    <p>
      Using the Game.Runner from the previous section. You can build a simple animation 
      by implementing the <b>update()</b> and <b>draw()</b> methods.
    </p>
    <p>
      Here are some bouncing balls
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

<canvas id="game">
  <div id="unsupported">
    Sorry, this example cannot be run because your browser does not support the &lt;canvas&gt; element
  </div>
</canvas>
```

Comment: Por favor, sé más concreto en tu pregunta: crea un [mcve] en el que podamos ver cómo falla (en lugar de código incompleto que no se puede ejecutar) y añade el error que recibes (en lugar de simplemente decir "_manda error_"). Ayuda a la gente a ayudarte.

Comment: Este es en lace donde tengo alojado el código completo http://maximusinter.x10.mx/pong/

Comment: Todo el código relativo a la pregunta debería encontrarse en la pregunta en sí y no en un sitio externo. Si el enlace que compartes se rompe o dejas de utilizarlo, entonces tu pregunta deja de tener sentido. Por favor, añade el [mcve] directamente en la pregunta.

Comment: listo, ya he actualizado y agregado los códigos, pero todo falla cuando hago la modificación en   pong js. al agregar esta linea ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);

Comment: He cambiado el código que compartías para hacerlo ejecutable. Aún así, da error en un sitio diferente al que dices por una causa diferente a la que mencionas. ¿Podrías revisarlo? Además, ¿podrías añadir el error concreto que te aparezca en la consola de JS cuando ejecutas tu programa?

Comment: Estos son los errores que me arroja Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined:

draw@pong.js:118
draw@pong.js:38
draw@game.js:241
loop@game.js:229      si borro la linea 118 o la comento      ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);    vuelve a funcionar, pero mi propósito es remplazar el circulo verde por una imagen de una pelota

Comment: Es obvio que va a darte error, si las variables `x` e `y` no las has definido en ningún momento. Intenta usando `this.x` y `this.y`. PD: Revisa bien el código incluido en la pregunta, porque se te ha olvidado incluir tu `game.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XD pues efectivamente, después de revisar tutoriales, pude solucionarlo de la  la siguiente manera, en pong.js remplace la funcion draw :D

```
  draw: function(ctx) {
  var img = new Image(10,10)
  img.src = "ball.png";
  var w = h = this.radius * 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = Pong.Colors.ball;
  ctx.drawImage(img, this.x - this.radius, this.y - this.radius, w, h);
  if (this.pong.cfg.footprints) {
    var max = this.footprints.length;
    ctx.strokeStyle = Pong.Colors.footprint;
    for(var n = 0 ; n < max ; n++)
      ctx.strokeRect(this.footprints[n].x - this.radius, this.footprints[n].y - this.radius, w, h);
```